# Is it possible to find the region of convergence of a signal directly from its laplace transform?

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm given the laplace transform of a function and asked to find its region of convergence (ROC). I'm not sure if I should first take the inverse laplace transform to get the original function and then find the ROC. Is there a way to directly get the ROC directly from the laplace transform?

Comment: Where are the singularities of the $F(s)$ in the complex $s$-plane?

Comment: @Dr.MV I don't understand what those are. Do you mean the poles and zeros?

Comment: Poles are singularities; Zeros are not.  But there are other types of singularities, such as branch cuts and essential singularities..

Comment: @Dr.MV The poles are 5, 3, and 1. How would I go about this in general?